# TFS 2015 Web Access - Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-web-access

I've just upgraded from TFS 2013.4 to TFS 2015, and all was looking good. Now the page content is not loading in web access due to the following errors on multiple lines: **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**.

For example, when trying to load the project page (http://[server]/tfs/DefaultCollection/[project]), I get the above error on lines 38, 44, 117, and 173.

Our configuration is all pretty straightforward, with the only addition being a hostname binding on the IIS site that uses port 80. We still use the default port 8080 for TFS configuration.

Any idea what may have happened to cause this error to start popping up? Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using? If I had to wager a guess, you're probably using an older, unsupported browser like IE8.

Comment: Chrome, Edge, Firefox... all supported versions. I've also tried hard-refreshes, etc... all to no avail.

Comment: Is your tfs environment behind "friendly" dns aliases? Check the URL that's coming back in the browser debugger.

Comment: No sir, it is not.  We have a DNS record that points to the IP Address of our TFS server, so that we also have a "friendly" url; however, I am experiencing these issues via the default URL ([server]:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/[project]), and all TFS configuration settings use the default URL.

Comment: Can you successfully load it on the app tier server itself?

Comment: Turns out the issue lies with a third party plugin (TFS Timetracker). Working with them on a resolution now.